# Migrate from relative paths in JS imports to webpack aliases with WebStorm automatically

Tags: javascript, webpack, webstorm, automated-refactoring

I want to replace all app-imports in some old project with webpack aliases, like

```
import { LS } from '../../../utils/noSSR';
```

to

```
import { LS } from 'utils/noSSR';
```

I know how to configure my WebStorm to make him understand aliases (moreover it should understand them out-of-box), but I don't know how to refactor all my current imports from relative paths to aliases wherever it's possible. The thing is there are hundreds and hundreds of imports and I'm looking for some automatization.

Is it possible to do such a refactoring with WebStorm?